# What is the best way to avoid data leaking in timeseries forecasting multiple labels?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, preprocessing, data-leakage

I'm predicting crypto pairs volume. I want to increase my accuracy by using one model for different pairs. Question is how to avoid timedata leaking?

Example n - pairs, t- time, m - features for each. I can put all data in one vector n*m and predict all pairs simultaniously, but it will be a lot of features and I don't like it.

If I'm using some embedding or one-hot for pairs, model can get sequence of all pairs at time t, but model will get future info.

What is the common/best approach to pass data in this situation? Maybe collect all pairs at time t in one batch, will it help?

Answer (score 2):

There are few strategies that you could use to avoid data leakage:

- Use Cross-validation: For the time series data, use `TimeSeriesSplit` from `sklearn`. [Link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html). It will make sure that you are not peaking into the future data.
- Avoid future data: This kinda make sense. But I am adding it because sometimes we forget to remove those features that are actually based on future data. For e.g. if you're predicting sales for next week, make sure that features do not contain information about sales from next week.
- Feature selection: Be careful when creating derived features from your raw data. These can easily cause leakage. For instance, using an aggregate function (like mean or sum) over the entire dataset would leak information from the validation/test sets into the training set.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about data-leakage between training examples. For example BTC/USD was learned at time T, ETH/USD is correlated with BTC/USD, so if we know future about BTC/USD at time-period T and learning ETH/USDT , is it correct data representation?

Comment: In this situation, It's better to train two model separately. One for BTC and one for ETH. So there won't be any correlation

Comment: Or you can avoid those features which shows relation between them

Comment: I think most of features are correlated, but maybe I can hide time feature

Comment: Try using TimeSeriesSplit as well. Probably it can handle it. Compare the training data result with the prediction data and then see if it's overfitting. If it is then remove features